# Why i can't access GCP active cloud shell?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

Suddenly i can't access it.
Steps I've done:

- Tried to access different project - can't activate cloud shell
- Tried to re-login in incognito - can't activate cloud shell
- Tried to use different gmail account and different project - can't
  activate cloud shell
- Tried to use different network - can't activate cloud shell

Note: Previous days i can access it, but now i can't. the common things between the 2 accounts is my name. Is it possible that google blocked any emails that have my name?
[image: GCP Error Message]

Comment: my other account uses my personal account as recovery account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what happened but after sometime i magically can access it. For me after exactly 24 hrs. Did not do anything to solved it. But for that time i don't have access i used the google cloud sdk in managing my project's resources. Hopefully this was helpful